# Comparing filenames between readdir() and __FILE__ - complication with french accents

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a website who's PHP gathers all other files in the same directory as the current script and generates a menu from this (this menu includes the current file that the script is running from).

While i generate the HTML for this menu from this list of filenames, I check each to see if the filenames are equal to the current file's name (through __ FILE __). If so, I apply a style to highlight that item in the menu.

My filenames have french accents given that the file names are used at the page titles too. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari and IOS doesn't work; the french accents mess this process up somewhere, because removing the french accents from my filenames fixes the problem.

Here is my code:

**Get all relevent files from current directory**

```
if ($handle = opendir(getcwd())) {
    $albums = array();
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(is_numeric(substr($entry, 0, 4))) array_push($albums, $entry);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

**Here is my string comparison, dumbed down, with their var_dumps: (filename cleaning not added, assume both vars give the name filename structure)**

```
for($i=0; $i < count($albums); $i++){
    echo var_dump($albums[$i]); echo var_dump(basename(__FILE__));
}
```

**With its resulting echo:**

```
string(26) "2010_Kalymnos,_Grèce.php" 
string(25) "2010_Kalymnos,_Grèce.php"
```

When I try to force them in UTF_8 or ASCII, to see how they'll handle the french accent, they convert the accents differently, but I have no idea what's to cause this. Is it the methods I used to get the fileanmes( __ FILE __, readdir()) ?

My HTML files are utf-8, in case this important. Setting my PHP specifically to UTF-8 too doesn't solve the problem.

**EDIT**

```
<?php echo bin2hex($albums[$i]); echo '<br/>'.bin2hex($originFilename);?>
```

Results in:

```
323031305f4b616c796d6e6f732c5f477265cc8063652e706870
323031305f4b616c796d6e6f732c5f4772c3a863652e706870
```

Of the two, the first hex string is the correct one.

Comment: `echo var_dump(..)`?!? What the...

Comment: @Prusprus: use `bin2hex` to see exactly what the difference is.

Comment: I don't see how the browser can make a difference here, this is a pure server side code. There must be some other issue. Maybe you try to pass "page names" in the url and have an encoding problem?

Comment: @Jon, clearly the hex lengths are not equal. Do accented letter take extra bytes? Would this count towards the additional HEX values?

Comment: @arkascha I agree, but it's clearly worth pointing out that they work with some browsers but not with others. I'm starting to wonder if __ FILE __ pulls the filename direct from the script, or from the request header (sent from the browser), resulting in a dependency of the encoding/charset used by the browser?

Comment: @Prusprus: Obviously. The point was to see exactly what the difference is and solve the problem that way.

Comment: Sorry no, the __FILE__ constant does NOT contain some value taken from a request header. It contains the name of the file opened by the php engine. However you should take a close look at how that name is encoded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the hex-encoded output, we can see how the two strings differ. The first one reads `65cc80` where the second reads `c3a8`. This shows that you are a victim of [non-normalized Unicode strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

The first sequence corresponds to the two Unicode characters `U+0065` ([LATIN SMALL LETTER E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/65/index.htm)) and `U+0300` ([COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/300/index.htm)). As you can see, concatenating their UTF-8 encoded forms gives the hex-encoded byte sequence `0x65cc80`.

The second sequence corresponds to the single Unicode character `U+00E8` ([LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm)), which encodes to `0xc3a8`.

What's going on here is that you have two byte sequences which are not bit-identical, but are logically equivalent by the Unicode rules. When you want to compare the strings you need either an encoding- and normalization-aware comparison function *or* you need to normalize the strings beforehand (you can then use a dumb comparison function such as string equality).

Unfortunately I don't know of any way to do a logical equivalence comparison in PHP, so the solution is to install the intl extension and use the [`Normalizer`](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) class to convert both strings to Normalization Form C with [`Normalizer::normalize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php).